# How can I access all the values in a list element based on an event listener in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's assume I have a list of elements and a button. I want to remove an element from the list when that element is selected and the button is pressed. How can I do that?.

Comment: Add code so we can see what you are doing and we can help assist.

Comment: list element as in `<ul>` ? Add a click event, look at the event target

Comment: I am going to rephrase this question.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question, you can try with event delegation and textContent property:

```js
  

  let ul = document.querySelector('ul')
ul.addEventListener('click',function(e){
if(e.target && e.target.nodeName === "LI"){
console.log(e.target.textContent)
}

})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>value1</li>
   <li>value2</li>
   <li>value3</li>
</ul>
```

In this way once you click on a li element, you get his value